# How to use cron job in Blitz.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma2

### information I looking for :(

How to implementing cron job using Blitz.js.

### what I done so far

have double-checked Blitz.js document.

### what I want ask

Does anyone know or have been done implementing cron job using Blitz.js??
simple sample code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue, trying to implement cronjobs in Express layer of Blitzjs/Nextjs stack, turns out there is a solution for that, in [blitzjs Documentation](https://blitzjs.com/docs/background-processing-with-quirrel).

It's implemented it using [Quirrel](https://quirrel.dev/#features) a queuing service for projects like NextJs & BlitzJs.

Plenty of code samples in the tutorial implementing how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a cron job on Blitz is not different than on Next.js.

First of all you have to define your serverless function, under the `/api` folder (at the root, not in the `rpc` folder).

Then, create your file, such as:

```
import { api } from "app/blitz-server"
import db from "db"

export default api(async (req, res, ctx) => {
  try {
    // Do something here

    res.status(200).json({
      message: `Success!`,
    })
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: `Error : ${e.message}`,
    })
  }
})
```

Finally, you just need to create a cron job that target your api route.

For this, you have several free options:

- You can use [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/)
- You can use [Netlify scheduled functions](https://docs.netlify.com/functions/scheduled-functions/), if your project is hosted on Netlify
- You can also set up a cron job manually on [Vercel](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-setup-cron-jobs-on-vercel#high-frequency-cron-jobs)

Otherwise, you have many third party options, but not always free.

Hope this helps